# Unable to create virtual directory

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express, hosts

I am working on a website which authenticates with Facebook, so that the user can sign in through his/her Facebook profile. I've seen similar questions like this one, but none that covers exactly my issue.

To test this Facebook authentication locally, I figured that some hacks were needed. You see, Facebook only allows redirects to certain domains after the authentication process. For these domains, `localhost` is not an option.

So I decided to do some research. I ended up changing my `hosts` file to point the domain `local.fablelane.com` to `127.0.0.1`. However, now it complains when I try to change the virtual directory in Visual Studio 2012.

First, I see this dialog after changing it.

[image]

I then click Yes and end up with this dialog here.

[image]

What do you suggest I try? How can I change my virtual directory? It is important that I find a way to do this either programmatically, through changing a file somewhere, or through the commandline. The reason for this is that I intend to make an automatic setup program that does this for me in the future.

Comment: Testing login on localhost works perfectly fine, if you make the right settings in your app dashboard.

Comment: Not for me. I set my URL like this: http://i.imgur.com/Bjm1Z.png, and I get an error like this: http://i.imgur.com/kRyPp.png

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to uncheck `Use IIS Express` and also add your new name `local.fablelane.com` as a binding to IIS, so that when VS tries to open the site URL, the host-header matches the site.

Also, is there any reason you need a specific port, rather than the default?  It should be fine with 80.

You haven't said which version of IIS you're using, but on 8, open IIS Admin, expand your machine-name, expand `Sites`, right-click on `local.fablelane.com` (or however you've named it), and select `Edit bindings` and add `local.fablelane.com`.

Comment: I'd changed my Default App bindings and had `localhost` removed but forgot. I had to re-add it to get the Virtual Directory creation to work. Why can't the IIS developers just write decent error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Try uncheck the option "Use IIS Express".

Answer (score -2):

Check if your website port number in IIS has been changed.If its changed edit bindings and change port number to 80

Answer (score -4):

In addition to the above, click on the override application root URL and paste the host name address which you have given in the Project Url.

It worked for me.